# VSCode suddenly opening panel at the bottom of the screen (ignoring settings)

Tags: visual-studio-code

I don't understand the change of the panel not being where it's supposed to be.

Suddenly, pressing command+J opens the panel at the bottom of the screen, instead of to the right. I have not changed anything in my settings, although this error message seems to have turned up in my settings since the last update;

Workbench › Panel: Default Location

```
With the introduction of the side panel, the panel position is no 
longer able to be moved in favor of moving view containers between 
the panels.
```

Googling this does not give me any results. What does it mean?! What side panel, if not THE side panel (which is now a bottom panel) are they talking about?

Comment: Are you using the Insiders version 1.64?

Comment: You're right, I'll revert to the previous version ‍♀️

Answer (score 3):

See https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/141349#issuecomment-1033046397 for an update on the changes made in v1.64 on this issue and inclusion in the recovery build soon.

##### The recovery build is out:

> In **v1.64.2** which hasbeen released. Put the Side Bar on the right and use the command `View: Move Panel Right` (or `Left` or `Bottom`). In one workspace with the setting Workbench > Panel: Default Location : right it put the Panel to the right of the Side Bar (so far right) but triggering the command fixed that. Editor | Terminal (Panel) | Side Bar. And working if put on the left too.

---

With the Recovey Build mentioned above, the following answer is largely "deprecated".  I'll leave it for historical purposes.

This behaviour, of moving the Panel to the bottom despite your `panelLocation` setting is the result of the new **Side Panel** coming to Stable v1.64.  The olde `workbench.panel.defaultLocation` setting has been deprecated and the Panel will remain at the bottom despite the `defaultLocation` setting.  [Apparently, "deprecated" in this case means ignored.]

But, now you can have the traditional `Side Bar` on one side, the new `Side Panel` on the opposite side and the `Panel` on the bottom.  Or turn off any of those.

> Replacing Panel Location
>
> As mentioned above, the new Side Panel provides similar functionality
> as moving the Panel to the left or right, yet improves on this by not
> forcing the move of the original panel. Along with view drag and drop
> between panels, the new Side Panel is replacing the option to move the
> bottom Panel.
>
> In light of that, we have deprecated the
> `workbench.panel.defaultLocation` setting as well as the Move Panel...
> commands in favor of similar commands Move Views From Panel To Side
> Panel (`workbench.action.movePanelToSidePanel`) and Move Views From
> Side Panel To Panel (`workbench.action.moveSidePanelToPanel`). The old
> commands will remap to the appropriate new command providing the
> similiar behavior. Though, we recommend updating your keybindings to
> the new commands.

[image: panel location commands demo]

See more here: [Release Notes: New Side Panel](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_64.md#new-side-panel)